# How can I subscribe to the size of an array in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I want to keep track of the size of an array, I thought something like this would work:

```
class CarListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()   
    @Published var ownedCarLength = 0

    init(){     

        CarRepository.$ownedCars.sink { _ in
            self.ownedCarLength = CarRepository.ownedCars.count
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

as this is called each time the array `CarRepository.ownedCars` is modified, however the value returned from CarRepository.ownedCars.count evaluates to 0 for some reason. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know what `CarRepository` and `CarRepository.ownedCars` are, but I'm guessing they're something like this:

```
class CarRepositoryType: ObservableObject {
    @Published var ownedCars = []
}

var CarRepository = CarRepositoryType()
```

The sink is called before `ownedCars` is updated. The new value is passed to the sink; you should read it there.

```
    CarRepository.$ownedCars.sink { owned in
        self.ownedCarLength = owned.count
    }
```